# boost::program_options: undocumented "*" feature discovered, now need custom validator that writes to a map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I recently discovered an undocumented feature of `boost::program_options`, namely that it accepts "*" as a special wildcard that allows declaration of a group of options with the same prefix, like this:

```
configOptions.add_options()
    ("item_*", value<int>(), "items");
```

This declaration worked as expected and recognized `item_1`, `item_3`, etc, while rejecting unknown options.
Well now the question is, how can I write a custom validate function
that will populate a map with options key and its value, like this:

```
map<string, int> itemsMap;
options_description items("items options");
    items.add_options()
        ("item_*",value<map<string, int>>(&itemsMap)->multitoken(), "items")
    ;
```

My question is - how do I get the key of the option being validated from within validate() function?

```
template <typename T> void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values, map<string, T> *, int)
```

Comment: which version of boost are you using? I recall [a proposed patch](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/12/173888.php) on the mailing list, but do not see it ever discussed on [trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/query?status=assigned&status=closed&status=new&status=reopened&component=program_options&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=milestone&order=priority).

Comment: Version 1.52.0. Check the files: options_description.cpp Line 87 and config_file.cpp Line 43 . As far as I understand, the guy also knew about this feature back in 2010.

Comment: Opened a [ticket on trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7933).

Comment: check the accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554842/boostprogram-options-parameters-with-a-fixed-and-a-variable-token

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through all arguments identifying which has the correct prefix or write a custom parser. The instructions for both options are in the correct answer of the link below:

[boost::program_options: parameters with a fixed and a variable token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554842/boostprogram-options-parameters-with-a-fixed-and-a-variable-token)

The iteration option might seem easier to understand (implement and read) but the custom parser seems good too (though I never used it).